# Coding practice - Which coding approach should I use?

Tags: java, coding-style

Sorry for such a vague title. Did not think of good one.

Situation:

1. Have a List of User objects.
2. Need to create array for UserInfo object.
3. UserInfo object is created is based on information in User object. (Currently has a method for this)

Which is better in such a situation?

1. Should I pass whole list of User to User to UserInfo conversion method.
2. or Should I loop over list of User and pass each user object to conversion method and get UserInfo for it.

Examples:

```
List<User> users = .....;
UserInfo[] userInfos = getUserInfoFromUser(users); //(conversion method will loop and generate array, then return it.)
```

or

```
List<User> users = .....;
UserInfo[] userInfos = new UserInfo[users.size()]
for (int j = 0; j < users.size(); j++) {
    userInfos[j] = getUserInfoFromUser(users.get(j));
}
```

In first approach we pass a big object(list of User) as an argument and in second we call same method multiple times.Which is better?

The size of User list will be range from 25-200 objects in it.

Comment: In the first version userInfos = getUserInfosFromUsers(users) without .get(j)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about having *two* conversion methods, one that takes a `User` and returns a `UserInfo` (this could and probably should be a constructor of `UserInfo`), and one that takes a List, does the looping and internally calls the first one?

The size of the list is not relevant.

Comment: I agree - the list method is more convenient for use right now and reduces bloat, but the single-`User` method is more modular and will be easier to re-use if your requirements change or are extended.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on how often you will doing this, because you don't want to repeat the same loop in multiple places in your code.

I would suggest creating two methods, one which returns the info for a single user and the other which returns info for a list of users:

```
public UserInfo[] getInfoForUsers(List<User> users) {
    UserInfo[] userInfos = new UserInfo[users.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < users.size(); j++) {
        userInfos[j] = getInfoForUser(users.get(j));
    }
    return userInfos;
}

public UserInfo getInfoForUser(User u) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first approach as it is simple, also, argument will be the address of the `users` object. So doesn't matter big or small in that case.

Answer (score 0):

In the both cases, Java passes reference to an object. In 1st case, it's reference to collection of Users and in 2nd to an User.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the first option: pass the whole array!

Reducing the number of function calls definitely pays out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference: in the first version the function implementation would do the second version. Furthermore probably would like to have a function User -> UserInfo.